# Why are my variables being 'taped over' by other ones?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am completely lost here. I made some code illustrating the problem:

```
_list_ = [1, 2]


def function(thing):
    return_list = []
    thing1 = thing

    for x in range(2):
        thing1[x] = 2
    return_list.append(thing1)

    thing1 = thing

    for x in range(2):
        thing1[x] = 1
    return_list.append(thing1)

    return return_list


print(function(_list_))
```

prints:

> [[1, 1], [1, 1]]

When I want it to print:

> [[2, 2], [1, 1]]

I have got no idea why this is happening, and help is appreciated.

Comment: also, do not name your variable like `_list_`, by which I mean neither use the underscores nor use the the word `list`. leading underscores are used to indicate internal members and `list` is a reserved type in python

Comment: I will refrain from doing so in the future, sorry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have used the variable name `thing1` twice, which means you're reusing that object. You would have to rename the second list for your code to work:

```
def function(thing):
    return_list = []
    thing1 = [0 for _ in range(len(thing))]

    for x in range(2):
        thing1[x] = 2
    return_list.append(thing1)

    thing2 = [0 for _ in range(len(thing))]

    for x in range(2):
        thing2[x] = 2
    return_list.append(thing2)

    return return_list
```

P.S.: I strongly suggest using better names for variables. `thing1` and `thing2` are not very informative.

Comment: I tried using this for the function, but it still printed [[1, 1], [1, 1]]. Also, sorry for the variable names! In my project they are different but I made separate code to demonstrate the problem since the original was full of unnecessary stuff

Comment: @MaxArmstrong yes, sorry for that, I've corrected the code. Now it works as you expected

Comment: My question was slightly misleading, here is a more in-depth version. The problem is that I can't simply add the numbers 2 and 1 (in my bad older version) to a variable to be printed, because the numbers in question depend on user input in the beginning of the program.

Comment: I wanted to, but there's a 90 minute delay on asking questions so I thought it would be simpler to change this one... Was it not?

Comment: @MaxArmstrong I didn't want to offend you, just imagine you're failing an exam, because there was something else to the question, that wasn't mentioned;) consider reverting the changes and creating another answer, I'll surely remove the downvote then!

Comment: sorry dude, I totally forgot what the original post was... I'll mark yours as correct again, since it was to the original question, and I've asked the new one separately now. Good day!

Comment: @MaxArmstrong no problem, you can always revert the question - just click edit a pick a version you want to go back to. I'll do that for you, good day to you too!